# How to notify the user in surface view when image is clicked with a flash and sound in screen

Tags: android, surfaceview

**What I am having:** I am having a surface view where i am capturing a image

**What I am trying to do:**

1. Once i captured the image I want to show a like a flash effect
   indicating image is captured and a sound that camera gives
2. How to achieve this

---

```
public class FrgCamera extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private String mFileUriCreated;

    @BindView(R.id.surfaceview) SurfaceView surfaceview;

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean previewing = false;
    private Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return init(inflater, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initOnActivityCreated();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        stopTheCamera(camera);
        unbinder.unbind();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        initSurfaceView();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        stopTheCamera(camera);
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.surfaceview)
    public void stopcamerapreview(View view) {

        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);

    }

    /**
     * INIT OnCreateView
     */
    private View init(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_camera, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * INIT OnActivityCreated
     */
    private void initOnActivityCreated() {

        getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceview.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                try {
                    FileUtil imgDevice = new FileUtil(getActivity());
                    mFileUriCreated = imgDevice.createFile(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Timber.d(e, e.getMessage());
                }
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }


    /**
     * Refresh Camera
     */
    public void refreshCamera() {

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.d(e, e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.d(e, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Surface view
     */
    private void initSurfaceView() {
        try {
            // open the camera
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setParameters(setCameraParams());
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.d(e, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

    }

    /**
     * SET the camera params for the device
     */
    private Camera.Parameters setCameraParams() {

        Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        ImgParmUtil imgParams = new ImgParmUtil(param);

        return imgParams.getImageParam();

    }


    /**
     * STOP the camera
     */
    private void stopTheCamera(Camera camera) {

        if (camera != null && this.previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            previewing = false;
        }

    }


}
```